# Any strategy to defeat the Undead Core?

Tags: cave-story

I have been struggling to beat him. I have the Spur, the Bubbler, the Knife, the Super Rocket Launcher and the Fireball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Undead Core is a tough boss, not just because you're fighting three boss enemies at once, but because there are 2 (or 3, depending on how you classify it) other boss fights that happen immediately prior to the final showdown.

The way I've always beaten the UC in the past is to focus on Sue and Misery first. Misery in particular can make the battle very frustrating, because her endless hordes of minions can make dodging all the other attack projectiles quite tough. Sue is easier to take out, but she does a moderate to high amount of damage, so unless you are confident in your dodging abilities, she should be the next to go.

Finally, the UC itself. I've found that trying to stay on the floating platforms in the room while attacking with the Spur helps a lot, since one of his more damaging attacks causes white energy blasts to cling to the floor and ceiling. Whenever you get the chance, get as close as possible and unleash as many rockets as you can - this does the most damage. However, if you find getting close to be too difficult in the hectic battle, taking potshots with the Spur from further away is also a viable alternative.

Other tips: Try to take as little damage as possible in the Misery and the Doctor boss fights. I know this can be tough, but the less damage you take, the more health you have in the tougher UC fight. Additionally, if you have the Life Potion that Jenka gives you earlier in the game, you can use it here as well (though I like to save it for the Ballos fight in hell).

Comment: Speaking of which... I have never managed to defeat Ballos, should I ask a question about a strategy for this boss?

Comment: @Exerion Yes, that would be a separate question.